# Relationship between largest independent set of edges and size of smallest vertex cover.

Tags: graph-theory

I am doing a homework question on graph theory and need some help getting started. The question I need to do is:

Prove that $β(G) \leq 2α'(G)$ where $β(G)$ is the set of the smallest vertex cover and $α'(G)$ is the size of the largest independent set of edges, so the largest matching in G.

I can kind of see intuitively how this would be the case, on a triangle graph or a  pentagon shaped graph or K5 I can see that this is the case. I know that every edge of a matching $M$ must be covered by a different vertex in the vertex cover so $β(G) \geq M$. Would then trying to prove that $M \geq \frac{β(G)}{2}$ when $M=α'(G)$ be the way to do this?

Any hints would be great, thanks.

Comment: One way to do it is to use the fact that $\beta(G) = n - \alpha(G)$, where $\alpha(G)$ is the size of a maximum independent set of $G$.  Try playing with that and see if you can come up with something :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a largest matching $M$ (of size $\alpha^\prime(G)$) and include both endpoints of each edge into a vertex cover $C$. Clearly, $\lvert C\rvert \leq 2\alpha^\prime(G)$: it remains to prove that $C$ is *indeed* a vertex cover (this will give the result, since the *smallest* vertex cover will be of size at most $\lvert C\rvert$).

For more, put your mouse over the area/hidden text below:

> Suppose by contradiction $C$ is not a vertex cover of $G$. This means there exists $e\in E$ not covered by any $v\in C$. In particular, none of the endpoints of $e$ are in $C$: but that means $e$ can be added to $M$, contradicting the fact that $M$ is a maximal (and largest) matching.